# Cards not staying horizontally aligned after running for loop

Tags: css, reactjs, api, for-loop

I am trying to align the cards horizontally and it worked fine before, but after I  pulled the data from the **API** and used *for-loop* to show the data in the browser the cards stacked vertically.

Here is the javascript code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import axios from "axios";

function Home() {
  const [ApiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const data = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/?format=json");
      console.log(data.data);
      setApiData(data.data.Product);
      return data;
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {ApiData.map((obj, index) => {
        let x;
        for (x in obj) {
          return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="card">
                {/* <img className="store-img" src={obj.image} alt="" /> */}
                <span>{obj.name}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Here is the CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1; 
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline; 
  flex: 1; 
  height: 16em;
  width: 12em;
  max-height: 18em;
  max-width: 16em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}

.store-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The [JSON](https://github.com/Ayush6543/Files_img/blob/main/data.json) File which I am using for this code

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `div` with class `container` in every loop iteration. Put loop inside `container` div.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import axios from "axios";

function Home() {
  const [ApiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const data = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/?format=json");
      console.log(data.data);
      setApiData(data.data.Product);
      return data;
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    
    <div className="container">
      {ApiData.map((obj, index) => {
        let x;
        for (x in obj) {
          return (
            
              <div className="card">
                {/* <img className="store-img" src={obj.image} alt="" /> */}
                <span>{obj.name}</span>
              </div>
            
          );
        }
      })}
  </div>
   
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your divs with class **d-flex** if you are using bootstrap or create a class with property display: flex. Try below code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import axios from "axios";

function Home() {
  const [ApiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const data = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/?format=json");
      console.log(data.data);
      setApiData(data.data.Product);
      return data;
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="d-flex">
      {ApiData.map((obj, index) => {
        let x;
        for (x in obj) {
          return (
            <div className="container" key={index}>
              <div className="card">
                {/* <img className="store-img" src={obj.image} alt="" /> */}
                <span>{obj.name}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```